# Вывод календаря по введённому пользователем месяцу и году. (C++)

Tags: c++, алгоритм, календарь

Всем привет. Я недавно начал учить C++ и сейчас у меня есть задание на написание календаря, но не совсем полного, а только по одному месяцу. Пользователь должен ввести месяц и год и на выводе получить табличку этого календаря. Давно я уже мучаюсь над этой задачей и вот казалось бы, почти решил, но что-то не так.
Если рассматривать 2021 год, то январь и февраль отображаются неверно, остальные месяцы в 2021 году правильно. В январе и февраля есть сдвиг на один день вперед, тоесть месяц начинается на день позже от положенного. Может, кто знает в чем проблема и сможет помочь кодом, буду очень благодарен!
**Вот мой код:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
int month,year;
string monthsList[12] = {"Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"};
int mDays [12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

cout«"Введите номер месяца: ";
cin»month;
while (month < 1 || month > 12)
{
cout«"Неверно введён месяц. Введите номер месяца от 1 до 12, где \n 1 - январь \n 12 - декабрь";
cin»month;
}
cout«"Введите номер года от 1900 до 2035: ";
cin»year;

while (year < 1900 || year > 2035)
{
cout«"Неверно введён год. Введите число от 1900 до 2035:\n";
cin»year;
}

cout«" —------------------------------"«endl;
cout«" Calendar - "«year«endl;
cout«" —------------------------------"«endl«endl;

/*
1) Определим номер дня недели, где:

0 - Понедельник
1 - Вторник
2 - Среда
3 - Четверг
4 - Пятница
5 - Суббота
6 - Воскресенье

*/

int days;
int current;
static int t[] = {0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4};
int y = year - 1;
current = (y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 + t[month - 1] + 1) % 7; // от 0 до 6

/*
2) Проверка на високосность начиная с нулевого месяца:
0 - январь
...
11 - декабрь
*/
if (int i = month - 1)
{
if( i==1 ) // 1 - это февраль месяц, так как счёт начинается с 0.
if (year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0))
days = 29; // Если високосный
else
days = mDays[i];
else
days = mDays[i];

/*
3) Выводим сам календарь
*/
cout«endl«" —----------"«monthsList[i]«"-------------"«endl;

cout«" Пн Вт Ср Чт Пт Сб Вс"«endl;

/*
4) Вводим доп. переменные k и j:
k - количество дней в неделе от 0 до 6 (0 - ПН; 6 - ВС)
j - количество дней в месяце (от 1 до общего в месяце)
*/
int k;

for (k = 0; k < current; k++)
cout«" ";

for (int j = 1; j <= days; j++)
{
k++;
cout«setw(5)«j;
if (k > 6)
{
k = 0;
cout«endl;
}
}

if (k)
cout«endl;

current = k;
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, для января вы сами режете вывод этим:

```
if (int i = month - 1)
```

Не экономьте на спичках, просто уберите этот `if` - вам же выводить в любом случае! - и напишите

```
    if( month == 2 ) // 1 - это февраль месяц, так как счёт начинается с 0.
        if (year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0))
            days = 29; // Если високосный
        else
            days = mDays[month - 1];
    else
        days = mDays[month - 1];
```

Во-вторых, используйте [правильный алгоритм](http://rusoul.ru/vychislenie-dnia-nedeli-po-date/):

```
static int t[] = {6, 2, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4};
int y = year%100;

current = y/12 + y%12 + y%12/4 + t[month-1] + (20-year/100);
if ((year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)) && month <= 2) current--;
current = current%7;
```

и [все заработает](https://ideone.com/XixZzh) :)